# Eclipselink Lazy loading fails when upgrade to Jersey2 for Weblogic 12c migration from WL11g

Tags: ejb, lazy-loading, eclipselink, weblogic12c

We are working to migrate an Java 7 - EJB(Remote implementation) application from Weblogic 11G to Weblogic 12C. As part of the migration we have upgraded to Jersey2(2.26) from Jersey1(1.17.1). Though Jersey1 is backward compatible we have upgraded for long run purpose.

The beans have been injected as EJBs and with its Remote implementations. In one of the Service layer method, child object is accessed from the parent entity that is retrieved from DAO layer(Entity is retrieved with EntityManager and JTA PersistenceUnit defined along with all the entities listed in persistence.xml). While trying to access that we are getting below error.

`Caused By: Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.7.v20190604-418f1a1c56): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.`

Eclipselink will create a temporary-read session for indirection/LAZY access out side of sessions as far as I know.

Why it is not working in 12c while it was working in 11g.
We haven't changed the Eclipselink version. It is still in 2.4.2 in pom.xml. (However as the 12c ships with Eclipselink 2.6.7 by default it is being used. I've read the documentation for Eclipselink 2.4.2 and 2.6.7) Not much of a change in terms of LAZY/EAGER Fetch and weaving.)
I have read that Weaving is enabled by default in JavaEE. So ideally the above error shouldn't have occurred.

To troubleshoot it further, I've simply made standalone main method class with direct DB connectivity with same eclipselink 2.6.7. I'm trying to access the child the same way after I've closed the EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory. That time it is working. Why it is not working in 12c alone? What am I missing here?

P.s.: I have upgraded javaee-api from 6.0 yo 7.0 as well. Just sharing. Also the packaging is changed to 'jar' from 'ejb' to make it compatible with 12c/Jersey2.

Update 1: Posting full trace to know if there are any internal serialization happened(as per Chris comment). P.s.: Updated my package name as com.foo.bar.foobar.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.7.v20190604-418f1a1c56): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:130)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy307.getMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.service.rest.InboxServlet.getMember(InboxServlet.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.service.rest.InboxServletHandler.doFilter(InboxServletHandler.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3797)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3763)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1720)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1680)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.7.v20190604-418f1a1c56): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that relationship is traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.instantiatingValueholderWithNullSession(ValidationException.java:1024)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.entity.Provider._persistence_get_address(Provider.java)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.entity.Provider.getAddress(Provider.java:193)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusiness.updateMemberAddress(InboxBusiness.java:1535)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusiness.updateMember(InboxBusiness.java:641)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusiness.getMember(InboxBusiness.java:403)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy367.getMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusinessRemote_lbjxju_InboxBusinessRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:54)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusinessRemote_lbjxju_InboxBusinessRemoteImpl.getMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.InboxBusinessRemote_lbjxju_InboxBusinessRemoteImpl_CBV.getMember(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy307.getMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.service.rest.InboxServlet.getMember(InboxServlet.java:374)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.foo.bar.foobar.service.rest.InboxServletHandler.doFilter(InboxServletHandler.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3797)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3763)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1720)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1680)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
>
```

Comment: EclipseLink allows triggering lazy outside of transactions as long as the entities themselves have access to the underlying session (EMF). As the error states, this is lost when they are serialized, which I would guess might be what is happening here. Serialization can occur even within the same JVM when using EJBs, and with your upgrades the where/when that might occur might have changed slightly and opened up this issue. The stack should show you where the lazy relationship is being accessed, and you can check/post how you get the entity to there from where you read it.

Comment: Yes @Chris . I've posted the whole trace for reference. Now to answer your question. DAO(InboxBean.java) and Service(InboxBusiness.java) classes are implemented as Remote EJBs. Parent entity retrieved in DAO entity. There the child is being tried accessed. The child can be access if I try within in DAO class itself. Out of that class everywhere the above error occurs.

Comment: You are using your EJB's remote interface to access the data, which as per the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83725/ejb4.htm ) serializes the in/out parameters, which nulls out all the instrumentation EclipseLink needs to fetch a lazy relationship. This might have worked previously if your access points were local, as I believe some containers don't always serialize the data to/from remote EJBs if they are within the same app, but should not have been expected to work. You'll need to use a local interface if it is local, or prefetch the data before returning it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris. The issue got fixed once I changed my EJB interface to Local from Remote. And yes you are right, it was trying to serialize as it is Remote interface and hence all the session information is lost and in turn lazy loading was not working. Can you please post it as answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83725/ejb4.htm), EJB's remote interface to access the data serializes the in/out parameters, which nulls out all the instrumentation EclipseLink needs to fetch a lazy relationship. This might have worked previously if your access points were local, as I believe some containers don't always serialize the data to/from remote EJBs if they are within the same app, but should not have been expected to work.

You will need to use a local interface if it is local, or prefetch the data before returning it.